# New PHPSESSID created when call a Database Query (using Directus)

Tags: php, mysql, session, directus

**Context:** I use XAMPP (with PHP version 7.0.29) and the headless CMS Directus.

**What I want to achieve:** I want to create single PHPSESSID based login. As a logged in user you have the possibility to access data in the database.

**What happens at the moment:** I can log in and also read out the data from the database. But in my /tmp folder of xampp I see, whenever a database query is performed, a new PHPSESSID file is added.

**Expected behavior:** When creating a database query, no new PHPSESSID file should be created.

**What i think:** Since I use Directus and the PHP SDK is in a subfolder of my PHP files, I could imagine that the PHP location gets mixed up and sets a new SESSION. Or that Directus needs a new SESSION for the database query. I'm not sure, so here's the thread.

Here are the most important excerpts from my files. And keep in mind my Frontend is located at localhost/html and the directus SDK is located in localhost/directus-build.

login.php (The Interface)

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

[...Login From...]

<script>
$("#login").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = $('#email').val(),
  password = $('#password').val();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "querys/login.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

querys/login.php (The logic)

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../vendor/autoload.php'; // Needed by Directus

$loginProcessor = \Directus\SDK\ClientFactory::create('TOKEN', [
  'base_url' => 'http://localhost/directus-build/',
  'version' => '1.1'
]);

// Check if email is in database
$userProcessor = $loginProcessor->getItems('users', [
  'filters' => [
    'email' => $_POST['email'] //i use POST here only for stackoverflow example
  ]
]);
```

When i remove the $userProcessor PHP wont create a new PHPSESSID File in /tmp. 
Obviously, the second PHPSESSID comes through the database query from Directus.

Comment: Have you checked whether the cookie gets send back to the server with the AJAX request, have you checked what properties the original and the new one (presumably the creation of a new session file goes along with a new session cookie value in the response?) where set with, especially regarding the domain and path?

Comment: I should send and receive the correct cookie with AJAX. The path and the session_id I receive are also the right ones. Both session files are stored in / tmp. The original file contains the properties set by me and the new one is empty. I can just imagine that a new session is started by $userProcessor, because the server starts this query. But maybe I'll do something wrong. How can I check the path and domain of the new session?

Comment: Use browser dev tools to find out what domain/path a cookie was set for. _“I can just imagine that a new session is started by $userProcessor”_ - well it looks like the culprit in some way or other, because you said if you remove this call, the problem goes away. Renewing the session id when the user’s login status or something else important changes, is quite a common practice - so that component might do it as well. Suggest you check the docs/and or code ...

Comment: Dev Tools only gives me my setted cookie back. Only in / tmp is a new file added. I have also removed my entire login script and only performed a database query with Directus and the SESSION file is also set. So it must be up to Directus. I contact the developers. If I have an answer, I'll come back again.

Comment: I have news, but no solution. I have written with the developers of Directus. The phenomenon is new to the team. Since all are currently in the development phase of Directus 7, the team is initially focusing on the major update. But they want to have a look at the conspicuousness sometime... Meanwhile I wrote myself a cronjob that deletes these sessions, that's enough for me.